# guest VM can't get IP address with bridge mode

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

I have one guest VM(windows 7) running on VMWare in the MAC OSX host. When I use "NAT" mode, the guest VM has no problem getting IP etc. to connect to internet. However, when I change to use "bridge" mode, the guest OS can't connect to internet. How to fix this?

1. The guest VM should connect to the vmnet0 in the host.
2. The vmnet0 bridges the guest VM to my physical router.
3. Since both the guest VM and the physical router have DHCP turned on, the guest VM should be able to retrieve the IP, gateway but the guest VM only has IP address and couldn't get on internet.

Comment: I fixed my problem by going to `Edit -> Virtual Network Editor -> change settings` and then in there, I selected the bridged virtual adapter from the list (VMnet0 in my case), then in the  `VMnet information` section, I changed the value of the `Bridged To` from `Automatic` to the correct adapter (my Wireless adapter in my case).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I had the same issue with VMWare Workstation 11.  It apparently started happening AFTER I upgraded to:
     11.1.2 build-2780323 
although it may have been the addition of a Juniper or Hamachi network client.

I had used "Bridged" for each VM but after the upgrade, I encountered connectivity problems.  After I set the NIC to NAT, it started working.

Here is how I was able to resolve the issue and start using "Bridged" network adapter again:

1. Go to File -> Edit -> Virtual Network Editor
2. Use the Change Settings" button
3. Highlight the first selection VMnet0
4. Under VMnet Information choose the "Automatic Setting" button
5. You will get a list of all of the adapters on your system.
6. Uncheck ones that might be causing the issue.
7. Click "Apply" then "OK"

Now, the "Bridged" setting should work or at least it did for me.  Go back and change any that you had changed to NAT to get them working.

Comment: I fixed by manually set up an IP/Gateway/Subnet.However, with both DHCP enable, why can't the guest VM get these info automatically?Is this a bug?

Comment: Worked for me in version 14. Lots of virtual adapters in the adapter list so that's probably causing the issues.

Comment: This just solved an issue for me in v14.  Had a few adapters that needed to be unchecked.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem. Seems after I had installed wireshark on my host, the bridge configure adapters had the npcap loopback adapter checked. When I unchecked that, it started working.

Comment: Same here, turns out nmap does not play well with VMWare in this case.

Comment: I confirm - ncap loopback adapter is the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, none of the other solutions worked for me. To solve this, I needed to do three things:

1. On my host (Windows 10), disable the firewall for the network type of my current network (Private)
2. **Restore Defaults** in the VMware Workstation Virtual Network Editor:

   [image: Virtual Network Editor screenshot]
3. Reboot VM

Answer (score -4):

**Setup**
Shut down all running VM's
Right-click on the VM > Change... > Network
Open Tab: Adapter 1
Enable the Adapter and select "NAT"
The next step is important to make it work:

**Open Tab: Adapter 2**
Enable the adapter and select: "Host-only Adapter"
Select Name: "VirtualBox Host-only Ethernet Adapter"
Click at "Extended"
Select the adapter: "Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop..."
Select the modus: "Allow all and host"
Click on "Ok" to save all settings.
Yes, you have to enable two adapters at the same time to make it work. Realy. You need a "NAT" and a "Host-only Adapter".

**Start the VM**
Open the terminal (with Ctrl+Alt+T)
Enter: ifconfig
Now you should see a local IP address like 192.168.56.104
The IP address is dynamic an can be different on your VM

**Test**
Go back into your host machine
Open the command line: cmd
Ping the guest VM with the command: ping 192.168.56.104
You should see the ping response
If you have a web server installed on the guest VM then open http://192.168.56.104 in your browser to the hosted website.